# Story identification: movie. Two warring cities on a distant world

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been trying to find this movie for years. I can't remember what year it came out but it must've been the 80's or 90's. The movie was about these two warring cities on a world covered in ice. A squad of soldiers is sent to the enemy city to end the war by blowing it up, the only problem is there is this giant ice or Crystal wall that's protecting the city and it kills anyone not authorized to be there. They wore body armor that mostly covered them and a snowy like camo. I remember the main characters father was a general who disappeared trying to reconcile the two cities and when he gets past the wall he finds his remains. I even remember a scene where the main character has to cut a bioidentificaion out of an enemy and put it in his mouth because it must be surrounded by living tissue to function. I clearly remember nearly the entire plotline of this movie but not the title or actors.

Comment: American production? Did you see it on TV or the cinema?

Comment: As I recall I watched the film on tv in the late 90's whether it was an American product or not I'm unsure but it was shown on American television. I'm almost positive it was a B movie. I believe I watched it on the Sci Fi channel before they changed the name.

Comment: So they were speaking English with American accents. Any chance you could recall or tell if the voices were dubbed?  My gut is hinting to me this might be a European movie. I don’t think the SyFy channel was creating their own B movies in the late 90s.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't believe they were dubbed but my memory on that aspect is hazy. I do remember they had a splitter type snow camo that was rather European though. The kind that's mostly sharp angles. On top of that in one scene they used and old school recoilless rifle mounted on a tripod to take out some rebels in one of the first scenes.